# Count pattern frequency in pandas dataframe column that has multiple patterns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below:

```
details = {
    'container_id' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
    'container' : ['black box', 'orange box', 'blue box', 'black box','blue box', 'white box'],
    'fruits' : ['apples, black currant', 'oranges','peaches, oranges', 'apples','apples, peaches, oranges', 'black berries, peaches, oranges, apples'],
}
  
# creating a Dataframe object 

df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

I want to find the frequency of each fruit separately on a list.

I tried this code

`df['fruits'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()`

but I get the black count 2 times instead of 1 for black currant and 1 for black berries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like you did, but with specifying the delimiter. Be aware that when splitting the data, you get some leading whitespace unless your delimiter is a comma with a space. To be sure just use another step with `str.strip`.

```
df['fruits'].str.split(',', expand=False).explode().str.strip().value_counts()
```

your way (you can also use str.strip after the stack command if you want to)

```
df['fruits'].str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
apples           4
oranges          4
peaches          3
black currant    1
black berries    1
Name: fruits, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the comma separator followed by an optional space:

`df['fruits'].str.split(',\s?', expand=True).stack().value_counts()`

**OUTPUT:**

```
apples           4
oranges          4
peaches          3
black currant    1
black berries    1
dtype: int64
```